# Why does Fragment exit animation not work?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm adding fragment with animation from bottom to top and then it should go from top to down when back is pressed or when popBackStack() is called.

```
val confirmFragment = ConfirmFragment.Companion.newInstance(item)
val transaction = MainActivity.getMainActivity(context)!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.addToBackStack(tag)
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top)
transaction.replace(R.id.over_view, confirmFragment, tag)
transaction.commit()
```

ExitAnimation (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

EnterAnimation (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1700"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

The enter animation works but when the fragment exists it doesn't work

Comment: You want : `setCustomAnimations (int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)` instead.

Comment: @Mark Keen Thanks
Please write your comment as answer and I could accept it.

Comment: How we can handle this same problem through nav_graph @Mark

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `set` tag in your xml code .

Change to this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1700"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p">
</translate>
```